# Capitalisation in titles

Tags: capitalization

Some of the examples:

1. Flow of Control between Layers
2. Layered Architecture: Schematic
3. Introduction to Aspect Oriented Programming(AOP)
4. POJO-based Programming Model

I can't decide whether to use capitalised form in titles and whether it is subjective or there are strict rules on this matter.

Did I capitalise correctly? Can I use abbreviations inside if I introduced them before?(4) What about dash in (4)? The word after dash should be capitalised?

Comment: They all look correct to me!

Comment: If you're submitting these for publication, consult your publisher's preferred style guide.

Comment: Don't worry about it. If you are punctilious in such matters you will only deprive some wretched graduate student of the miserable pittance she earns for bringing your manuscript into conformity with the publisher's arbitrary house rules.

Answer (score 1):

Titular capitalization is a matter of style, and is not prescriptively laid out via some rule.

As a general guide, however, you should seek to capitalize all of the important and emphatic words in a title. In contrast, small "supporting" words such as *a*, *an*, *and*, *a la*, *but*, *by*, *for*, *from*, *in*, *if*, *of*, *on*, *above*, *the*, *to*, *etc*, *with*, *vs.* and so on tend to go uncapitalized.